# How is current file location calculated in vim? (value of expand('%:p'))

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete

While using the (excellent) Python autocompletion of YouCompleteMe (Jedi apparently) sometimes I'm suddenly unable to save because what vim thinks the path to my current file changes. When I open a file with `vim bpython/curtsiesfrontend/repl.py`, running

```
:echo expand('%:p')
```

gives me

```
/Users/tomb/Dropbox/code/bpython/bpython/curtsiesfrontend/repl.py
```

but after I use the completion, the same command gives

```
bpython/curtsiesfrontend/repl.py
```

and I can no longer save the file because that's not a path that exists. `:pwd` gives `/Users/tomb/Dropbox/code/bpython` before and after - so there must be some other part to the equation "what is the full directory path to this file."

I'm wondering what vim commands or concepts I should be looking at to identify the issue. There must be some concept of current directory of a file that is changing (however vim calculates the value of `expand('%:p')`) but I don't know what to call it. What is the concept of current directory that is changing?

Comment: Something like that should not happen, even when Vim's CWD changes. Open an issue against YouCompleteMe.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I agree it's an issue with YouCompleteMe - I'm curious about how to investigate it. Will edit question (and will open bug, thanks for the suggestion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current file location is relative to Vim current path, which can be set with `:cd` or `:lcd`.

In order to identify where it is being changed you could use the `'verbose'` option along the `:redir` command:

```
redir @a
set verbose=9
<execute the steps to reproduce the issue>
redir end
set verbose&
new
put a
```

Then search for 'chdir'. Increasing the value of `'verbose'` displays more information, but it also make it harder to execute each step to reproduce the issue. After identifying a smaller test procedure you could repeat these steps using a higher value for `'verbose'`.

Comment: My problem was slightly different, and now I can't remember what it was :( but this answer was helpful